# Android - Fade Image Button on click

Tags: android, android-layout, imagebutton

I have an image button in a layout and implemented the onclick functionality for the same. Now, i want to fade the image button during **"on click"**. How to do fading the image programatically in android. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement an animation on a button. You must have a View animation with a alpha element. Read this : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource.html                                                                                                                                                                                 and if you need any help please write here...

Answer (score 1):

Like this (I havent tested it, but should work), but you need to have "faded" version of ImageButton drawable.

```
Bitmap iconOn = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.icon_on);//this should be yours faded button image
Bitmap iconOff = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.icon_off); //and this will be normal image

Drawable iconOnDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(iconOn);
Drawable iconOffDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(iconOff);

StateListDrawable states = new StateListDrawable();
states.addState(new int[] { android.R.attr.state_pressed },iconOnDrawable);
states.addState(new int[] { android.R.attr.state_focused },iconOffDrawable);
states.addState(new int[] { android.R.attr.state_selected },iconOnDrawable);
states.addState(new int[] {}, iconOffDrawable);

ImageButton imageButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button);
imageButton.setImageDrawable(states);
```

Answer (score 0):

This way is how you do it:

```
Button b = view.findViewById(R.id.button);
   final TransitionDrawable td = new TransitionDrawable(new Drawable[]{new ColorDrawable(0xFFFF0000), new ColorDrawable(0x11FF0000)});
   b.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if(event.getActionMasked() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            //b.setBackgroundColor();
        }
        if(event.getActionMasked() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            b.setBackgroundDrawable(td);
            td.startTransition(1000);
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```